# sqlalchemy migrate postgres tables to oracle

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I was asked to migrate a postresql database using SQLAlchemy to oracle. I installed both psycopg2 and cx_Oracle, and wrote the following to migrate

```
 copy_table(source, target, table_name):
    """
    Copy a single table
    :param source: Database: source database
    :param target: Database: target database
    :param table_name: str: table to copy
    :return: None
    """
    metadata = MetaData(bind=source.engine, schema=source.schema)
    table = Table(table_name, metadata, autoload=True)
    try:
        table.create(target.engine)
    except DatabaseError as e:
        return False
    return True
```

The problem is I get the following error for every table:
(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
[SQL: 
...
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

I looked to find a fix, but it doesn't seem that anyone goes from Postgres to Oracle. I know some of the issues are with VARCHAR and being replaced by VARCHAR2. Is there a workaround? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Whatever tool it is that you're using to generate the table DDL is not creating valid Oracle syntax. If you can post the CREATE TABLE statement we can point out the syntax error to you. But configuring the tool to generate it correctly might be harder.

Comment: Oracle has some great migration tools, see https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/migration.html  If you are doing big data transfers in cx_Oracle, then review the cx_Oracle documentation https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html and https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#tuning-fetch-performance